# Convert hex little endian to decimal number

Tags: vb.net, hex

I understand how to convert decimal to hexadecimal (little endian).

Dec : 579270022
Hex : 86F58622 (little endian)

My sample code:

```
Public Shared Function decimalToHexLittleEndian(ByVal _iValue As Long, ByVal _iBytes As Integer) As String
    Dim sBigEndian As String = String.Format("{0:x" & (2 * _iBytes).ToString() & "}", _iValue)
    Dim sLittleEndian = ""

    For i = _iBytes - 1 To 0 Step -1
        sLittleEndian += sBigEndian.Substring(i * 2, 2)
    Next

    Return sLittleEndian
End Function

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    TextBox2.Text = decimalToHexLittleEndian("579270022", 4)
End Sub
```

**Now, my question is how convert hexadecimal (little endian) to decimal?**

Comment: (Note that [Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal) is a type in VB.NET, so it's probably better to write it as decimal with a lower-case "d" when you mean a number written in base-10.)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the pairs of characters and then use `Convert.ToInt64(r, 16)`:

```
Dim h = "86F58622"

' Ensure an even length
If h.Length Mod 2 = 1 Then h = "0" & h

Dim r = ""
For i = 0 To h.Length - 1 Step 2
    r = h.Substring(i, 2) & r
Next

Dim a = Convert.ToInt64(r, 16)

Console.WriteLine(a) ' outputs 579270022
```

Comment: Got it..:) Thanks a lot. You save me lot of time.